# Why did Joseph Joestar not become a vampire?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

At the end of season 2 of Stardust Crusaders, the blood from Dio's corpse was transfused back to Joseph Joestar. However, as seen before in the series, the contact of Dio's blood with a corpse makes the corpse a Vampire. It was also explicitly stated that Dio's body was still not "dead". Then why did this not happen to Joseph?

Answer (score 1):

The Best Possible explanation, that I can think of is that Joseph was a Hamon User, and Hamon is anti-Vampire, so it somehow protected him from turning to a Vampire.

Comment: But production of Hamon requires a person to breathe. And given that even his heart had stopped, he most definitely was not able to breathe.

Comment: also Straizo was a Hamon user yet he became vampire after using the mask. And even after becoming a vampire he was able to keep Hamon in his body, which was revealed at the time of his death

Answer (score 1):

Well, Joseph, from the moment of his birth has been filled with Hamon; Hamon is-well a vampire repellent. Think of vampirism as raw meat, and Hamon as a fire. Raw meat is bad, but after being purified, the meat is now safe. It also might be because of his Hamon infused blood that it wasn’t fully digested by DIO and therefore was easily taken back.